# Sequelize.js: query for object without relations

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

The [Sequelize documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/#relations-associations) is very limited when it comes to querying relations:

[image]

For example, I would  like to query all `Project`s with no `Task`s that have a state OR description defined (therefore, either these projects have no tasks at all, or they only have tasks that have only a state or only a description, but not both).

You might think something like this would work:

```
Project.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: Task,
        where: {
            $or: {
                state: null,
                description: null
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

However, this doesn't work because it wouldn't return any `Project`s that have no tasks at all.